# Run a (R) script as a service [server 2012R2]

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, windows-service

(complete windows noob here, I've been using Linux since a kid)

If I just run:

```
C:\Progra~1\R\R-3.4.0\bin\x64\Rscript.exe  C:\Users\NPX9sx9000010190CAL\Desktop\el_leo\code_15.R
```

in the windows server DOS terminal as an administrator, it works fine.

Now I need to run this script as a service (policy of the place that pays me food);

I looked a bit on the internet and put this in the windows server DOS terminal:

```
sc create myRScript5 binPath= "cmd.exe /c C:\Progra~1\R\R-3.4.0\bin\x64\Rscript.exe  C:\Users\NPX9sx9000010190CAL\Desktop\el_leo\code_15.R" DisplayName= "My R script 5"
```

The service is correctly displayed in the list. I right click and press 'start'. 
I get:

```
Error 1053: The Service did not respond to the start request
```

I have also tried some more or less inspired variants such as:

```
sc create myRScript3 binPath= "C:\Progra~1\R\R-3.4.0\bin\x64\Rscript.exe \"C:\Users\NPX9sx9000010190CAL\Desktop\el_leo\progtest.R\"" DisplayName= "My R script 3"
```

I must be doing something stupid but I do not know what. FWIW here is code_15.R

```
setwd("C:/Users/NPX9sx9000010190CAL/Desktop/el_leo")


library(doSNOW)

print('boom')
set.seed(123)
x = runif(10)
write.table(x, 'yahoo.txt')
```

## EDIT

Some I am trying SqlACID solution (probably botching it somewhere).

I installed srvany.

I created a file

```
C:\Users\NPX9sx9000010190CAL\Desktop\el_leo\rrr.bat
```

that contains:

```
C:\Progra~1\R\R-3.4.0\bin\x64\Rscript.exe  C:\Users\NPX9sx9000010190CAL\Desktop\el_leo\code_15.R
```

I start the windows terminal as administrator and ran:

```
sc create "MyFirstService" binPath= "C:\Temp\SrvAny.exe" start= auto
```

I get

```
[SC] CreateService SUCCESS
```

from the windows terminal. I start RegEdit and found

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\MyFirstService
```

I created a key Parameter

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\MyFirstService\Parameters
```

Inside it, I created a new string Application of type REG_SZ and with value_data:

```
C:\Users\NPX9sx9000010190CAL\Desktop\el_leo\rrr.bat
```

Then, I go to Services, find MyFirstService and right click Run;

I got

```
Error 2: The system could not find the file specified
```

Comment: Do you absolutely need to run this as a service? What about running it as a scheduled task from a batch file?

Comment: I have to ask someone about there rules. I'm on site now, trying your solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Services are expected to respond to start/stop requests in very specific manners, and cmd.exe is not able to do that; there used to be a "service wrapper" that would encapsulate a generic executable as a service, it was provided with the [Windows Server Resource Kit](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=17657), look for SRVANY.EXE, I have no idea if it would function with newer OS's or whether there are alternatives, but it's worth a try.

OP resolved the issue by using a scheduled task running a batch file rather than a service.

OP here: A collegue contributed the following:

```
schtasks /create /sc ONCE /tn OP /tr C:\Users\NPX9sx9000010190CAL\Desktop\el_leo\R.bat /st 09:35
```

Comment: Tried you solution (Thanks!) but I must have botched something because I get a different error now

Comment: Running it as a scheduled task from a batch file solved the problem

Comment: great news.  glad to help.

Comment: Should I accept your answer? I'm not sure what to do; Thanks for the help

Comment: Not required but always appreciated! I updated the answer with your resolution.